# Getting FR_3085 ERROR when working in Informatica

Tags: informatica

In a lot of the task flow jobs I'm running, I constantly am getting the

> FR_3085 ERROR: Row [1]: 2-th character is a null character, which is
>   not allowed in a text input file

error. These occur usually in data synchronization tasks but I sometimes see this in mapping configurations as well. How do I resolve this error?

Comment: Start by doing some data quality up front to prevent these characters entering your etl in the first place i.e. why is your sending system embedding nulls in valid text?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you have NULL characters in your flat file.

One way for doing this is using the OS utilities for removing the NULL characters from your flat file automatically and this will depend on what OS you're using.